# python: pandas: Merge multiple tables according to a index table

Tags: python, pandas, merge

For example, I have three tables A, B, C

Table A:

```
id1   value1
1     23
2     34
3     2342
4     333
```

Table B:

```
id2   value2
1     apple
2     banana
3     berry
```

Table C:

```
id3   value3   value4
1     red      batman
2     green    superman
3     white    wonder woman
4     gray     aquaman
5     yellow   flash
```

I want to merge these three tables according to an index table D

Table D:

```
Table_A    Table_B    Table_C
1          3           2
3                      4       
2          2           3
4          1           1
                       5
```

And my resulting table should like:

```
id1   value1    id2   value2    id3   value3  value4
1     23        3     berry     2     green    superman
3     2342                      4     gray     aquaman
2     34        2     banana    3     white    wonder woman
4     333       1     apple     1     red      batman
                                5     yellow   flash
```

Can I do it via Python Pandas or I need do it in Spark?

Comment: Look at `map` rather than `merge` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
table_d['value1'] = table_d['Table_A'].map(table_a.set_index('id1')['value1'])

table_d['value2'] = table_d['Table_B'].map(table_b.set_index('id2')['value2'])

table_d.merge(table_c, left_on='Table_C', right_on='id3')
```

Output:

```
   Table_A  Table_B  Table_C  value1  value2  id3  value3        value4
0      1.0      3.0        2    23.0   berry    2   green      superman
1      3.0      NaN        4  2342.0     NaN    4    gray       aquaman
2      2.0      2.0        3    34.0  banana    3   white  wonder woman
3      4.0      1.0        1   333.0   apple    1     red        batman
4      NaN      NaN        5     NaN     NaN    5  yellow         flash
```